# Creating curved labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I added an image, that explains my demand (see Schiefelsbach river).
How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: for me is the same, I wanted to set my label like that image, but when I clicked 'curved' the label is disappeared, I have to do it only 'parallel', the label is displayed but not the shape I wanted.How do I keep the labels while using 'curved'?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134395)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134395)

Comment: okay guys, I'm sorry, I'm now trying to delete my "comment" but I couldn't, I'll try more to delete these as soon as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [OSM guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ogo958kIG7Hp4mrrrsJRgeNS4m0or9t05rI5FK4nDK8/edit) outlines how to make labels follow line features, in addition to providing good guidance on other common label styling tasks.

The steps are to select the layer labeling settings tab and then select 'advanced' from here you can choose 'curved' labels which follow the contours of a line.

Comment: Oh..I see now; I used the plugin "easy custom label" what is (for labeling) a MUST, since the default labeling is not good at all..At any rate; It produces a point layer, so this option was not available. For Line layers it is... So, you ve got an Idea how to do it, when my label layers is a point layer?I guess I have to figure out a special solution for it then.. thanks at any rate.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how you would go about it for point layers. I don't have QGIS installed on my office machine so I can't test anything at the moment.

Comment: Hm...I have a problem with that method; When I choose "curved labels" like the guide says, the label disappears. Do you know why/ what the requirements for curved l. are?

Comment: Its hard to know for sure but I would imagine it may be a conflict issue with other labels, you could try playing with the priority values for your labels.

Comment: it did not disappear. It just was resized very small... Well, once you move the label the curving gets disabled and you cannot do it again...Definately a possibility for a new plugin...

Answer (score 1):

The option is called "curved" if I remember correctly and you can find it in Advanced tab of the new labeling dialog.

Comment: Will it auto get the segment curve? (I'm on the roads now...) or is it a manual set?

Comment: it's automatic.

Comment: It worked , but I had to use parallel and not curved , since they are in LTR lang. using curved changed the order of the letters while parallel kept it.
Thx !!!

Comment: @Anita Graser, I am using QGIS 1.8.0. I don't see any curved or parallel labeling property in the advanced tab.