# How do I set label to rotate with segment in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create curved labels in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/how-to-create-curved-labels-in-qgis)

In MapInfo Pro I have an option to rotate a label with segment (this is nice for labeling roads for example).

How do I do the same in QGIS ?